# iOS NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil only in one instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Does NSDateFormatter have a propensity for unexpectedly returning nil? I wouldn't think it did.
I am hoping that I have overlooked some miniscule detail which for whatever reason I cannot see.

I have some data describing the sun and moon. It's listed below.
I also have a loop which iterates over this data once it is loaded from its plist into a dictionary.
Finally I have a class which processes dates for me using NSDateFormatter as a singleton.
This process has worked pretty well and these methods have been interacting and producing correct dates for a month or two, but today it crashed. All of the strings being created and passed through this simple process are correctly converted into dates except the last one which is nil. 
Here's what happened:

This is the data in the property list.

```
<key>2014-3-7</key>
<dict>
    <key>moonrise</key>
    <string>10:51 am</string>
    <key>moonset</key>
    <string>0:03 am</string>
    <key>phase</key>
    <string>Waxing Crescent</string>
    <key>sunrise</key>
    <string>6:39 am</string>
    <key>sunset</key>
    <string>6:21 pm</string>
</dict>

<key>2014-3-8</key>
<dict>
    <key>moonrise</key>
    <string>11:39 am</string>
    <key>moonset</key>
    <string>0:56 am</string>
    <key>phase</key>
    <string>First Quarter</string>
    <key>sunrise</key>
    <string>6:38 am</string>
    <key>sunset</key>
    <string>6:21 pm</string>
</dict>

<key>2014-3-9</key>
<dict>
    <key>moonrise</key>
    <string>1:28 pm</string>
    <key>moonset</key>
    <string>2:45 am</string>
    <key>phase</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>sunrise</key>
    <string>7:37 am</string>
    <key>sunset</key>
    <string>7:22 pm</string>
</dict>
```

This data is processed through a loop creating dates from date strings starting with yesterday and ending tomorrow, so in this case it starts on the 7th or march and ends on the 9th and we are working with the values in each plist item for the given date as a dictionary called iDay.

```
NSString *eventString;
NSDate *moonrise;
NSDate *moonset;
NSString *dateFormatString = @"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a";

if ([iDay objectForKey:@"moonrise"] != nil) {
    eventString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", dateString, [iDay objectForKey:@"moonrise"]];
    moonrise = [self.dateTime makeDateFromString:eventString
                                          format:dateFormatString];
}

if ([iDay objectForKey:@"moonset"] != nil) {
    eventString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dateString, [iDay objectForKey:@"moonset"]];
    moonset = [self.dateTime makeDateFromString:eventString
                                         format:dateFormatString];
}
```

The strings being passed to [self.dateTime makeDateFromString] by these statements look like this:

> 2014-3-7 10:51 am
>
> 2014-3-7 0:03 am
>
> 2014-3-8 11:39 am
>
> 2014-3-8 0:56 am
>
> 2014-3-9 1:28 pm
>
> 2014-3-9 2:45 am

Okay, good. Now the dateTime singleton:

```
+(ADateTimeClass *) sharedDateTime {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == NULL)
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter new];
        self.dateFormat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

... and the method where it all goes horribly wrong. All of the strings passed to this method get returned correctly as dates except the last one, and I've checked, the nil is coming from "[dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]" right here where dateString is one of the six I listed above.

```
-(NSDate*) makeDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString format:(NSString *)format{
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:format];
    NSDate* aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    return aDate;
}
```

And the results:

> Printing description of moonrise: 2014-03-07 14:51:00 +0000
>
> Printing description of moonset: 2014-03-07 04:03:00 +0000
>
> Printing description of moonrise: 2014-03-08 15:39:00 +0000
>
> Printing description of moonset: 2014-03-08 04:56:00 +0000
>
> Printing description of moonrise: 2014-03-09 16:28:00 +0000
>
> Printing description of moonset: <nil>  <------------  !!!!!!
>   Huh???

Comment: Can you also show the exact instance  that causes this problem (and maybe put the ones that do work along with the created date)? Something like `NSLog(@"Date from \"%@\" is \"%@\".", string, date);`

Comment: From your input (2014-3-7 10:51 am) and the corresponding output (2014-03-07 14:51:00 +0000) it seems that you are not using the date formatter created by `sharedDateTime` and therefore *not* doing the conversion in UTC.

Comment: Hi there all. Yes I see what you are saying. I need to recheck that. It does seem pretty obvious that rmaddy is right and I had cleverly forgotten DST. Thanks for pointing out the discrepancy. I'll post back about that.

Comment: Yep the time zone is wrong, but so are these values I gave you. The routine is handing me back dates that match like 10:51 == 10:51 but the new date is marked as AST or ADT and the only failure is the date that falls right there in the lost hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple problem actually depending on where you live. At least in the USA, any time from March 9 2014 between 2am and 2:59am won't exist due to daylight saving time change. Therefore any such date is invalid.

Comment: Also discussed in [WWDC 2011 Video "Session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there is no good way to detect this, since you need a date to test it to find out if it's DST. Seems like I need to a) do this in an unnecessarily elaborate fashion that takes DST into account by using NSCalendar and b) Make sure I am really using UTC.

Comment: You'll want to set your date formatter to locale en_US_POSIX to prevent interference from user preferences.

Comment: @NFG: for date calculation you should always use a calendar, as it is the calendar who transforms a point in time, represented by a NSDate instance, into meaningful time and date. It is a calendar who knows about days, not the nsdate object.

Comment: @NFC: another option could be to do all computations on NSDateComponents. Also covered by the video.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I'm afraid I have to admit to willful laziness there. I'm well aware that these classes exist and that I am supposed to use them, but I did not in this case. It's pointy hat time!

Comment: @NFG: good programming is about being lazy — but being correct as-well. You could define a category on NSDate that hides the calendar.